# If non-zero vectors $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ are equally inclined to coplanar vector $\vec c$, then $\vec c$ can be

Tags: vectors

> If non-zero vectors $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ are equally inclined to coplanar vector $\vec c$, then $\vec c$ can be
>
> - A)$\;\dfrac{|\vec a|}{|\vec a|+2|\vec b|}\vec a+\dfrac{|\vec b|}{|\vec a|+|\vec b|}\vec b$
> - B)$\;\dfrac{|\vec b|}{|\vec a|+|\vec b|}\vec a+\dfrac{|\vec a|}{|\vec a|+|\vec b|}\vec b$
> - C)$\;\dfrac{|\vec a|}{|\vec a|+2|\vec b|}\vec a+\dfrac{|\vec b|}{|\vec a|+2|\vec b|}\vec b$
> - D)$\;\dfrac{|\vec b|}{2|\vec a|+|\vec b|}\vec a+\dfrac{|\vec a|}{2|\vec a|+|\vec b|}\vec b$

**My Attempt:** If $\vec a,\vec b$ are equally inclined to $\vec c$ then $\dfrac{\vec a\cdot\vec c}{|\vec a||\vec c|}=\dfrac{\vec b\cdot\vec c}{|\vec b||\vec c|}\implies\left(\dfrac{\vec a}{|\vec a|}-\dfrac{\vec b}{|\vec b|}\right)\cdot\vec c=0$

Not able to proceed from here.

In the hint, they have witten that $\vec c=t\left(\dfrac{\vec a}{|\vec a|}+\dfrac{\vec b}{|\vec b|}\right)$. Not able to understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$(u - v) \cdot (u + v) = u \cdot u - v \cdot v = |u|^2 - |v|^2.$$
So,
$$\left(\dfrac{\vec a}{|\vec a|}-\dfrac{\vec b}{|\vec b|}\right) \cdot \left(\dfrac{\vec a}{|\vec a|}+\dfrac{\vec b}{|\vec b|}\right) = 1^2 - 1^2 = 0,$$
as the two normalised vectors have norm $1$.

The formula given, for $t = 1$, produces such a $\vec{c}$. Any multiple will also satisfy the above equation, by the multilinearity of the dot product. So, indeed, the provided formula for $\vec{c}$ in the hint is guaranteed to be a solution.

With this in mind, B) is a solution. Note that,
$$\dfrac{|\vec b|}{|\vec a|+|\vec b|}\vec a+\dfrac{|\vec a|}{|\vec a|+|\vec b|}\vec b = \dfrac{|\vec b||\vec a|}{|\vec a|+|\vec b|}\dfrac{\vec a}{|\vec a|}+\dfrac{|\vec a||\vec b|}{|\vec a|+|\vec b|}\dfrac{\vec b}{|\vec b|}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $u = \dfrac{a}{|a|} , v = \dfrac{b}{|b|} $

You've derived that $ (u - v) \cdot c = 0 $, but $c = \alpha u + \beta v $ because it is coplanar with $a$ and $b$, hence,

$ (u - v) \cdot ( \alpha u + \beta v ) = 0 $

Expand and use the fact the $u \cdot u = v \cdot v = 1 $

$ \alpha - \beta + (u \cdot v) (\beta - \alpha) = 0 $

And this becomes after factoring,

$ (\beta - \alpha) ( u \cdot v - 1 ) = 0$

**Case I:**  $u \cdot v - 1 = 0 $, then $u$ and $v$ are the same vector, hence,

$ c = (\alpha+\beta) u $

**Case II:** $ u \cdot v - 1 \ne 0$ then $\beta = \alpha$, hence,

$ c = \beta ( u + v ) $

Comment: Thankyou.......